# Why do X11 applications start but their windows stay invisible?

Tags: macos, macports

After using a fresh OS X system for a while, I regularly hit the point where X11 clients start and run, but their windows do not show up anywhere.

I suspect it has something to do with Mac port paths, but i am not sure. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I have recently installed ghostscript and for some reason X11 starts whenever I use gs, but no windows appear. Not sure if my issue is related to yours, but I'm interested in a solution as well :-)

Comment: This sounds similar, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit of a workaround, but you could try installing [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki), a newer version of X11. It bypasses X11 rather than replacing it, so you should be able to uninstall it again if you want Apple's X11 back.